# Unable to post request using redux-observable and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-observable

I'm trying to do a POST request in React using Redux, redux-observable and Typescript. (It's my first time using redux-observable and Typescript just to let you guys know where I come from...) I can't get an epic to work it keeps showing a Typescript error.
And I'm stuck here for hours... please I need some help!

Before putting the Axios function everything worked well. See code below:

```js
  const locationEpic: Epic<Action, Action, RootState> = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(actions.setLocation)),
    map(action => {
      const { payload } = action;
      return { type: LOCATION_SET, payload}
    }
  ));
```

Axios of post request:

```js
interface LocationState {
  path: string;
  name: string;
}
interface AxiosResponse {
  data: LocationState;
}
const postData = (data: any) => {
  return axios.post<AxiosResponse>(baseURL, data)
  .then((res: any) => {
    console.log('post', res.data);
  })
  .catch((err: any) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
};
```

The problematic epic:

```js
const locationEpic: Epic<Action, Action, RootState> = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(actions.setLocation)),
    switchMap(action =>
      from(postData(action.payload)).pipe(
        map(actions.setLocation(action.payload)
    ))
  ));
```

I keep getting this error:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{
>   type: "@@location/SET"; payload: LocationState; }>'.   Type 'unknown'
>   is not assignable to type '{ type: "@@location/SET"; payload:
>   LocationState; }'.

Comment: Your map() doesn't look right, it should be a function and you're giving it  an action object. Would expect something like `map(response => actions.setLocation( <<something using response>> ))`. Also you're mapping to the same action that the epic is handling so this would result in an infinite loop which I'm guessing isn't what you want.